# Redirect NServiceBus message based on Endpoint availability

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus5

I'm new to NServiceBus, but currently using it with SQL Server Transport to send messages between three machines: one belongs to an endpoint called `Server`, and two belong to an endpoint called `Agent`. This is working as expected, with messages sent to the `Agent` endpoint distributed to one of the two machines via the default round-robin.

I now want to add a new endpoint called `PriorityAgent` with a different queue and two additional machines. While all endpoints use the same message type, I know where each message should be handled prior to sending it, so normally I can just choose the correct destination endpoint and the message will be processed accordingly.

However, I need to build in a special case: if all machines on the `PriorityAgent` endpoint are currently down, messages that ordinarily should be sent there should be sent to the `Agent` endpoint instead, so they can be processed without delay. On the other hand, if all machines on the `Agent` endpoint are currently down, any `Agent` messages should not be sent to `PriorityAgent`, they can simply wait for an `Agent` machine to return.

I've been researching the proper way to implement this, and haven't seen many results. I imagine this isn't an unheard-of scenario, so my assumption is that I'm searching for the wrong things or thinking about this problem in the wrong way. Still, I came up with a couple potential solutions:

1. Separately track heartbeats of `PriorityAgent` machines, and add a mutator or behavior to change the destination of outgoing `PriorityAgent` messages to the `Agent` endpoint if those heartbeats stop.
2. Give `PriorityAgent` messages a short expiration, and somehow handle the expiration to redirect messages to the `Agent` endpoint. I'm not sure if this is actually possible.

Is one of these solutions on the right track, or am I off-base entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not seen many do this because it's considered an antipattern. Or rather one of two antipatterns.

1) Either you are sending a command, in which case the RECEIVER of the command defines the contract. Why are you sending a command defined by `PriorityAgent` to `Agent`? There should be no coupling there. A command belongs to ONE logical endpoint/queue.

2) Or you are publishing an event defined by whoever publishes, with both `PriorityAgent` and `Agent` as subscribers. The two subscribers should be 100% autonomous and share nothing. Checking heartbeats/sharing info between these two logical separate entities is a bad thing. Why have them separately in the first place then? If they know about each other "dirty secrets," they should be the same thing.

If your primary concern is that the `PriorityAgent` messages will not be handled if the machines hosting it are down, and want to use the machines hosting `Agent` as a backup, simply deploy `PriorityAgent` there as well. One machine can run more than one endpoint just fine.

That way you can leverage the additional machines, but don't have to get dirty with sending the same command to a different logical endpoint or coupling two different logical endpoints together through some back channel.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Deploying `PriorityAgent` to the `Agent` machines as a backup is a good idea, which was blocked by a client requirement that `Agent` machines only process `PriorityAgent` messages in case of a failure. However, we were able to change the requirements such that we can now install the `PriorityAgent` on `Agent` servers and just leave it off, allowing the client to manually switch it on if it becomes necessary. This should allow us to continue using NServiceBus in a way consistent with its intent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Dennis van der Stelt and I work for Particular Software, makers of NServiceBus.

From what I understand, both `PriorityAgent` and `Agent` are already scaled out over multiple machines? Then they both work according to *competing consumers* pattern. In other words, both machines try to pick up messages from the same queue, where only one will win and starts processing the message.

You're also talking about high availability. So when `PriorityAgent` goes down, another machine will pick it up. That's what I don't understand. Why fail over to `Agent`, which seems to me to be a logically different endpoint? If it is logically different, how can it handle `PriorityAgent` messages? If it can handle the same message, it seems logically the same endpoint. Then why make the difference between `PriorityAgent` and `Agent`?

Besides that, SQL Server has all kinds of features (like Always-On) to make sure it does not (completely) go down. Why try to solve difficult scenarios with custom build solutions, when SQL Server can already solve this for you?

Another scenario could be that `PriorityAgent` should handle priority cases. Something like preferred customers, or high-value customers. That is sometimes used when (for example) a lot of orders (read: messages) come in, but we want to deal with high-value customers sooner than regular customers. But due to the amount of messages coming in, high-value customers would also end up in the back of the queue, together with regular customers. A solution could be to publish these messages and have two different endpoints (with different queues) subscribed both to this message. Both receive each unique message, but check whether it's a message they should handle. The `Agent` will ignore high-value customers, the `PriorityAgent` will ignore regular customer.

These are some of the solutions available as standard messaging patterns, or infrastructural solutions to solving your issue. Again, it's not completely clear to me what it is you're looking for. If you'd like to continue the discussion; perhaps you want to email support@particular.net and we can continue the discussion there.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I edited my question to try to clarify the situation, but it's closest to your latter scenario. `PriorityAgent` should indeed handle priority "orders", while everything else can wait on the longer `Agent` queue. If I go with your suggestion of both endpoints subscribed to the message which ignore messages not intended for them, how would the `Agent` machines know that the `PriorityAgent` machines are down and have to start processing messages intended for the `PriorityAgent`?